# Why does int variable throw an error, but not an int literal when assigned to a byte variable?

Tags: java, type-conversion

I have recently begun to learn Java, and couldn't just understand one feature of the language.

When I write the code below I don't get any error (and sensibly I shouldn't!):

```
byte b = 10 * 2
```

However when I type in the following code, the compiler throws an error:

```
int i = 10;
byte b = i * 2
```

When the compiler can perform a check on `10 * 2` to ensure that it's less than the range of `byte`, why can't it also perform a check on `i * 2` and see whether it's less than the range of `byte`?

Has it got something to do with lower-level representation of bits, or something related to memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not positive on anything Java-specific, but any modern compiler would perform constant-folding to "fold" expressions that are entirely constants. I.e., 10 * 2 folds to 20 so the compiler treats it as if you typed `byte b = 20;`

It is not really practical for a compiler to try and optimize for variables. Even though in your provided example it is relatively simple to look at and know that `i` is `10`, if a compiler would try to optimize that and know what `i` was, it would have to maintain it's own symbol table and would essentially be an interpreter. Since java is a pre-compiled language, this defeats the purpose.

**Elaborating:**

There is a difference between a compiler and an interpreter. A compiler takes in source code as input, and writes machine code behind the scenes. When that machine code gets run, operations/executions/calculations are performed. Java is a compiled language, so it's compiler is not doing much computation, it is just writing machine code that can be run on a Java Virtual Machine. Python on the other hand, is an interpreted language. When you run a python program, it won't try to do any type conversion for `i * 2` until after it actuall evaluates `i * 2`.

Now, sometimes compilers try to get smart, and have built in "optimizations." What this means is instead of writing machine code that does some operation, they write machine code in fewer instructions because it knows what it will be (so the compiler does *some* computation to achieve that). In your example, rather than write machine instructions that store the number 10, store the number 2, multiply them, then store the result, the compiler can multiple the 10 and 2, and just write a machine instruction to store that result.

When we introduce variables, it becomes harder for the compiler to optimize and figure out what that variable is. The actual compiling program (the Java compiler) would have to remember that i is a variable holding the number 10 right now. If we want to optimize just to know we can assign i * 2 to the `byte`, that would mean the compiler would have to remember every single integer variable on the off chance that it gets assigned to a byte in a later expression - at that point it isn't really worth the optimization as the compiler is spending extra computation (extra work to compile) that doesn't really give any benefit. A symbol table (mentioned above) is essentially a table remembering the variables and what their values are.

Comment: Interesting... but as I said I am a beginner, I would really love if you could somehow explain this in simple words.. I definitely think you know about the problem.

Comment: Sure thing - check out my edit with the elaborating section.

Comment: Really good explanation... So I think it is difficult for the compiler to evaluate the value of an integer variable at compile time and therefore would've to do extra work in performing the check on variable expressions.. right?

Comment: Yep exactly that. Even though in some cases it is easier than others, it is hard to write a general optimization that can check integer values at compile time.

Comment: This also means that ```final``` constants are also optimized by the compiler, that is they are inlined with their values wherever they occur in the source code...

Comment: In the other examples people are showing where they cast i * 2 to a byte ( `(byte) i * 2`) then yes it is computed at runtime. At compile time, the compiler just checks that your assigning an int to a byte but doesn't know how big that integer is so it complains.

Comment: Yes exactly! If you declare i final I would imagine this compiles.

Comment: Just one thing left is that with your discussion in mind, why does the ```int i =  500L``` statement throw an error.. ```500L``` is now a constant value..

Comment: My guess is that it all comes down to what the compiler has implemented. It looks like it has functionality to check that an int can be assigned to a byte if it knows that the int is in a certain range, but when assigning long to int it doesn't bother doing that check. Somewhat makes sense - but I can't give a definitive answer here.

Comment: In general with Java - you can use typecasts as long as you know your code will work. I.e. you as a programmer know that `int i = (int) 500L` is ok - the compiler isn't going to waste extra time doing that check for you if it only ever makes use of that functionality on rare occasions - it's easier just to check the types line up (int can assign to int).

Answer (score 5):

In java whenever you try to execute an arithmetic expression, Java converts all the elements of that expression into the highest data type available in that expression if the expression contains any kind of variable.

therefore,

When you do 10*2, Both the operands are literals, not variable and hence there will not be any automatic promotion of data type of operands and result as well unless the result exceeds the range of the data type which here is byte and 20 comes quite under the byte range.

But when you do i*2, Expression consists of variables where i is an int, and the result is 20 However, its type will int. Because the operands were automatically promoted to int, that is here 20 will be promoted to int when the expression was evaluated, the result will be int because of both operands are int. And an int cannot be stored in a byte even though it's under its range. because the compiler will think if stores an int in a byte there will be loss of value.

So, In this case, you have to forcefully typecast it to byte.

```
byte b = (byte)(i*2);
```

Try running this you will be amazed:

```
byte b = 10;
b = b * 2;
```

The explanation for this is still the same as mentioned above.

Comment: I have been reading that integral literals in Java are of type ```int```. So isn't```10 * 2``` also treated as ```int```?

Comment: Yeah, that's true, but in case of an arithmetic expression, it tries to typecast back to normal if there was no promotion of data type have taken place while evaluation of the expression.

Comment: But then why do ```final int i = 10``` not cause an error?

Comment: If a primitive type or a string is defined as a constant, the compiler replaces the constant name everywhere in the code with its value.

Comment: This is called a compile-time constant. But if you try to initialize a final variable with an expression like: `final int i = p*20;` then you will get the error. because the expression will be executed at runtime and so there will be no replacement of the final variable will take place.

Answer (score 1):

Some languages allow compilers a lot of freedom to be as smart as they can.

But Java is *not* such a language. One goal of Java is that you can compile your code with many different compilers and get the same result each time, so that you simply don't have to worry about whether your IDE and your local command-line compiler and your production build system all handle your code the same way.

So the reason that your compiler rejects

```
int i = 10;
byte b = i * 2;
```

is that it could only accept it if *all* compilers were required to accept it; which means that the specification would have to specify the exact range of conditions where compilers are and are not expected to figure out the value of `i` at compile-time. It would be a complicated mess, and every compiler would have to get it exactly right.

So, instead, the specification defines constant expressions in a fairly straightforward way (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28), and only allows implicit narrowing conversions when the right-hand side is a constant expression within the range of the relevant type (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2).

You can work around this, of course, by writing a cast, so as to perform an *explicit* narrowing conversion:

```
int i = 10;
byte b = (byte)(i * 2);
```

but the compiler won't check for you that `20` is in range of `byte`; you'll need to do that yourself.

Alternatively, you can make `i` constant:

```
final int i = 10;
byte b = i * 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

While it certainly wouldn't be beyond imaginable compiler analysis of this code to figure out that the calculation result will indeed fit into a byte in this specific case, `i` has nevertheless been declared to be an `int`, so I suspect the compiler will therefore applies the rules for *any* possible `int`, and with any possible `int`, the assignment doesn't work.

Comment: But then what about the fact that even 10 * 2 contains two ```int``` literals?

Comment: They are integers, but they are literals and constants, not specifically declared to be integers, and I suspect that makes a big difference to the compiler. Plus most compilers will pre-calculate constant arithmetic, rather than doing it at run time, so in this case the result is known to be byte-compatible at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Here `i` is an integer and so is `i*2`. You are assinging an integer variable into byte which is illegal. You can do this by casting it to `byte` explicitly.

```
byte b = (byte) (i * 2);
```

Java does not perform any value evalution to see if it can fit/unfit into the target type.

Answer (score 0):

The point is:

```
int i = 10;
byte b = i * 2
```

is really "clear", isn't it. A human understands that `b` **must** have a value of 20, and that 20 very well fits into the byte range.

But assume:

```
int i = someMethodCall();
byte b = i * 2
```

Now, when looking at that `someMethodCall()` body, **maybe** you could come to same conclusion. But you would agree: that alone makes it more complicated to decide whether `i*2` is still in the byte range.

Long story short: compilers can (and do) apply all kinds of analysis on source code. For example to compute things at **compile time** where possible. But *what exactly* happens depends on A) the language spec and B) the compiler implementation.

Thing is: it is super simply to write a compiler that simply says: "using an int value to init a byte value isn't valid". It is quite some more effort to write a compiler that is able to decide "here it is valid" all by itself. And then, there will be many cases, where the compiler doesn't know, and comes back complaining anyway.

In other words: the people creating java opted for a *simple* compiler. That makes the compiler easier to implement, but it results in the user receiving such error messages, that (theoretically) could be avoided (for many cases, not all).

Comment: But what about ```int``` literals? Doesn't the compiler do perform checks there?

Comment: @coderboy Sure, as the other answer says: the generic principle is called **constant folding**. But your example is not only about constant folding, it is also about conversion from one type to another. And that alone is a really complicated topic: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, by the way! I will surely go through it.

Comment: @coderboy You are very welcome. Just drop your upvote(s) and accept where you think they make sense.